# When does a flex application store a digest of an optimized RSL?

Tags: apache-flex, digest, rsl

According to the Adobe help in order to optimize a RSL you need to do the following:

> 1. Create an RSL by compiling a library project in Flash Builder or building a SWC file with the compc command line tool.
> 2. Compile your main application and reference the RSL.
> 3. Extract the library.swf file from your RSL’s SWC file, if you haven’t done so already.
> 4. Run the optimizer against the library.swf file
> 5. Run the digest tool against the optimized library.swf file
> 6. Deploy the optimized library with the application so that the application uses it at run time.

But I don't understand at what stage does the application store the new digest that was generated at stage 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recompile your main app that loads the RSLs with the verify-digests compiler option set to true.  This then reads the digests out of the SWC files that are specified to be used by the application and writes them into the main compiled app.

Comment: here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf674ba-7ff6.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ad2

Comment: Wow.  I had no idea.  :)  Updating answer.